# Using group in Entity Framework to return model and count

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have some data, similar to this

```
Email   Date        Id
Anne    1/1/00      1
Anne    1/2/00      2
Anne    1/4/00      3
Bert    1/4/00      4
Bert    1/5/00      5
```

I'm trying to return the following 2 results from the above into something like

```
List<Model, Count>
```

Where Model is a class with Email and Date (most recent Date) properties, and count is the total count

```
  var m  = (from e in emailOpens
                      group e by e.EmailAddress into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Model = g.Key,
                          Occurance = g.Count()
                      }).ToList();
```

The issue is, the above will return only the email addresses but I change the group statement to

```
group e by e into g
```

Then naturally there is nothing to count, so my Occurrence property remains at 0

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you expect to get as Model? For example *Bert* sent two emails with different `Id` s and at different `Date` s, which one you expect to get?

Comment: @AdilMammadov, I'm sorry, silly error on my part. I've made the edit to make it correct. I didn't need to use ID. For clarity, I'm after the most recent (by date) and a count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing just one statement:

```
var m  = (from e in emailOpens
                      group e by e.EmailAddress into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Model = new
                          {
                            Email = g.Key, 
                            // Select maximum date from group
                            MostRecentDate = g.Max(m => m.Date)
                          },                              
                          Occurance = g.Count()
                      }).ToList();
```